# Matplotlib: putting together figure, xaxis, minor_locator, major_locator

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a very basic plot putting several parameters together. This is how far I have come. Unfortunately the documentation and its examples does not cover my issue:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(50,18), dpi=60)
dax_timeseries_xts.plot(color="blue", linewidth=1.0, linestyle="-", label='DAX') 
# dax_timeseries_xts is a XTS with dates as index

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=(1),interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d\n%a'))
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="minor")
ax.yaxis.grid()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n\n\n%b\n%Y'))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Where do I create the "ax" in order to make this work? 
Or maybe I am not efficiently putting the arguments listed above together to create my chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fig, ax_f = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
```

will give you the axes

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the axes now. But the figure command does not work anymore now...

Comment: @caliph the line in this answer will *replace* your figure command (those keywords will work with this also)

Comment: Thanks: used fig, ax_f = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(100,18), dpi=60) and now all problems solved!